# python 2.x or 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since there is a python 3.x, why don't we use it?

Why do we still use 2.x?
What's the difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python 2.6 and 2.7 have been written to ease the transition to Python 3.
It will take some more time to port the more complex packages (i.e. those with many dependencies, or libraries written in C).

So if you are starting new projects, and all the libraries you need are there, it makes sense to start with 3.1. One of the more welcome changes is the handling of Unicode strings by default - it will prevent a lot of bugs.

But if you were to port a complete ERP application, or anything big, from 2.6 to 3.x, it could be a bloodbath right now. The unicode changes for instance are the hardest to apply from 2.x -> 3.x, and the low level C APIs have changed a lot as well.

Answer (score 8):

Because 3.x isn't backwards compatible with 2.x and a lot of apps and libraries are written for the 2.x series. 3.x was their attempt at cleaning up all the crud that never should have been in Python in the first place.... and they had to make some breaking changes. Probably best to stick with 2.x for now, til 3.x gains a bit more popularity.

Comment: Yeah, I think the main thing holding a lot of people back is the absence of Python 3 versions of many popular libraries.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest differences are listed in the [documentation of Python](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Hth. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're writing a new app, and don't rely on libraries that have no 3.x support yet, I suggest you go for 3.x.  Let's create some critical mass :)

Take a look at the [python 3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) itself

Answer (score 2):

Because lots of libraries are not yet ported to 3.x I guess... And because lots of application still run on 2.x