# What is the recommended version of python for Django framework?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

*Note: I have never done something like this before(Completely Newbie), just abit on Python 2.7.3 like a year ago.

As the title I have check out some of the question but it was way back to 2011-2013.

I would like to make a simple website, work kind of like kickstarter,in addition, have no realtime-chat. Just a simple post/comment section.

And yes I know the downside is the supported library but the problem is I don't know any of the library that I should be using on.

Which version should I use? Any suggestion?

I have been research on this 
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3#fnref-4fcb00922956f144dafd52e4f75d82631e225d1b

Comment: Why not directly check the `django` installation guide? It says that Django works with python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3.

Comment: I have already check it, but not sure which one to use.

Comment: See: [What Python version should I use for Django?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/faq/install/#what-python-version-should-i-use-with-django)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nowadays (Feb 2017), the choice is absolutely clear to me - *Python 3.* Django fully supports it since 1.6 and, moreover, [Django 2.0 will be *Python3.5+ only*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.0/#python-compatibility).

To check whether your dependency supports Python-3.x or not, use [Can I use Python 3?](https://caniusepython3.com/) service. Also, check [Django Packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/) directory of reusable Django apps - besides other features there is an indication whether a package supports 3.x or not.

Also, there were a lot of topics about the subject:

- [What Python version should I use with Django?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-should-i-use-with-django)
- [New project: Python 2 or Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938786/new-project-python-2-or-python-3)
- [python 2.x or 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253430/python-2-x-or-3-x)

---

**Old Answer:**

This is basically a question whether to choose Python-2.x or Python-3.x.

[Should I use Python 2 or Python 3 for my development activity?](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) article in Python docs says:

> Which version should I use?
>
> Which version you ought to use is mostly dependent on what you want to
>   get done.

Since you don't know your requirements yet - then, just to be safe, better stick to 2.x branch. Currently, it has a lot more batteries for all sort of tasks, and not all of them migrated to Python-3.x. Note that it is important to stick with the latest release, in case of 2.x branch - currently, it would be [`Python 2.7.7`](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.7/).

Comment: Yeah, there were too much topic about this which make me hesitate about it. Thanks for the suggestion :).

Comment: How about now in 2017? is 3.x good to go with?

Comment: @FreeKrishna nowadays, it is absolutely and definitely 3.x. Django has plans to drop support for Python 2 in Django 2.x. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Good to know. Im just starting up with python. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the latest version of 2.7 - you really can't go wrong there.

In a year or two my answer might be 3.x, but for now there's better library support for 2.x

Comment: It's two years later... Did your answer change? :)

Comment: Yup! I'd use Python 3 for new projects wherever possible. The library support is pretty comprehensive now.

Answer (score 1):

With the current and older versions of Django, you can use up to version 3.2 or 3.3, but I believe Python 3.5 is not supported until Django releases the new version 1.7 - which everyone is waiting for, because then we can delete the line called 'south' from our requirements.txt.