# When i type Python it shows python 2.7 when i type python3 it shows Python 3.5 version

Tags: python

This is when ı type **python**

```
yolcu@yolcu:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

this is when i type **Python3**

```
python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Is there anything wrong? what does that mean to me ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you _expecting_ it to show?

Comment: no everything is correct, python provides different Interpreter. There are differents between version2 and 3. https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Comment: You have two versions of python installed, python2.7 and python3.5. Is this different from what you expected?

Comment: I am starting to learn Django and i want to make sure i do python set up correctly.. so having both versions confused me or does that mean i can  take advantage of both versions?

Comment: Meet a decision first, if you want to develop in python2 or python3. I prefer python3, and django supports python3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737326/what-is-the-recommended-version-of-python-for-django-framework

Comment: ok, i prefer using python3 .. should i go ahead to remove python2? and  i will also every time type python3 to make sure i am using the latest version. Is that correct behaviour? I am a newbie so pardon me for silly questions. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are on Ubuntu system,

Ubuntu still needs python2 to run some of it's core services behind the scene. It is completely normal and nothing to be worried about.

by default python command shows python version 2.7 and python3 as python 3.5.

You can install anaconda to manage python version and packages as per your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will install anaconda

Comment: you're welcome, happy coding :)